# Android Studio tutorial app crashes

Tags: android, kotlin

I know this question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280786/android-official-tutorial-app-crashes) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), but since my Android Studio example tutorial app is compiled with a 3 years younger API, and the error looks like having a different cause, I figure it's reason enough to ask it anew.

I was closely following the Android SDK Guide Build your first App and I do it all in Kotlin, not Java. I also differ from the suggested compatibility level (I am using Android 7.0 API 24). The app compiles ok (only 1 warning bout *NDK is missing a "platforms" directory*). Whether I run it on my Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0 API 24 or on the virtual Nexus 5X with API 27, the app crashes when it is [launching the Second activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to display the message.

There are two activities: Main activity which has an EditText containing some text field and a button to send the text of it as EXTRA_MESSAGE in an intent to the Second activity which is supposed to display it.

Code for the Main activity:

```
package com.altran.tutorialapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

const val TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.altran.tutorialapp.MESSAGE"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    //** Called when the user taps the send button */
    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val writtenTextView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = writtenTextView.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Code for the second activity:

```
package com.altran.tutorialapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView


class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)
    }

    // Get the intent that started this activity and extract the string
    val message = intent.getStringExtra(TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    // Capture this layout's TextView and set its string to the string of the EXTRA
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
```

And here is the excerpt from logcat with the virtual Nexus 5X, which is the same error I get also in a proper bug report on Galaxy S6

```
03-16 18:14:20.786 3843-3843/com.altran.tutorialapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.altran.tutorialapp, PID: 3843
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.altran.tutorialapp/com.altran.tutorialapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.altran.tutorialapp.DisplayMessageActivity.<init>(DisplayMessageActivity.kt:16)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

But I don't know how to prevent this. The stack trace points to the line

```
val message = intent.getStringExtra(TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE)
```

and Android Studio shows this hint:

> Declaration has type inferred from a platform call, which can lead to
>   unchecked nullability issues. Specify type explicitly as nullable or
>   non-nullable. This inspection reports functions and
>   properties that have platform type. In order to prevent unexpected
>   errors, the type should be declared explicitly.

When I rewrite the line as ...

```
private val message: String = intent.getStringExtra(TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE)
```

... the same error happens. What else can I do? This is my first app and first Kotlin code, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this. You are calling intent when before activity created. Let me know if it helps. Also take a look at here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html you can use kotlin view binding instead of findViewById.

```
class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)
        //Get the intent that started this activity and extract the string
        val message = intent.getStringExtra(TUTORIAL_EXTRA_MESSAGE)

        // Capture this layout's TextView and set its string to the string of the EXTRA
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = message

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that worked indeed. I simply did not notice that the two variables have to be assigned within the domain of onCreate. Mea culpa.

Comment: Happy to hear it helps.